# How to parse a PDF using AS3? (air)

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf, air

is there a way to parse a pdf using AS3 via Air in mobile?.

I don't need the full content of the PDF, only some data, is that possible?.

Edit for clarification:

I got a PDF file that was originally created based on a XML, what I'd need is to be able to retrieve that XML. Or at least, to find a string inside that PDF so I can make a call to a web service.

Comment: I am not aware of any library that can do this using pure AS3. You may need to implement native extensions and use some other library behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Original:
There's nothing native in AS3 for this kind of stuff but [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/). It won't let you traverse things like XML so much, as it seems like you're trying to do by taking a small bit of a PDF, but it will let you create pdf's, add pages and change fonts etc.

You weren't entirely clear on what you're attempting to achieve, if you update your question a with a bit more detail we may be able to help a bit more.

Edit:
From the refined question, AlivePDF is not what you're after as it's really only for PDF generation. I'm assuming you're after a method to traverse the document like you would XML, by looking for a tag and extracting the information. I've not found a way to do this other than iterating through the document and searching manually which probably isn't what you're after.

After some searching I found an [as3-pdfreader](https://code.google.com/p/as3-pdfreader/) which doesn't seem to be complete at the moment. However on the Project Home the roadmap says parsing pdf files is complete, I've not been able to try it out yet though.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't clear enough, I edited it a bit.

Comment: @Artemix edited my answer. Hopefully that provides a push in the right direction however I've never found a tool other than the one linked that claims to do it in the same / as quick way as XML traversal. Thus my answer may not be hugely useful, but I'll keep digging for you.

Comment: @Artemix little update. I just found this which looks like it may be what you're after https://github.com/sephiroth74/purePDF